# Bootstrap 4 collapse save after page reload in desktop only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to save **collapse show/hide** after page reload in desktop only. The below example the collapse should open default when desktop view after page reload using **LocalStorage**.

I have tried the below example.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function() {
        //store the id of the collapsible element
        localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
    });

    var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem'); 
    if (collapseItem) {
       $(collapseItem).collapse('show')
    }
})
```

```js
function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 992) {
        $('.link').click(function() {
            //store the id of the collapsible element
            localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
        });

        var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem');
        if (collapseItem) {
            $(collapseItem).collapse('show')
        }
    } else {

    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its working for me https://codepen.io/iamguley/pen/xxbpeEv

Comment: @Gulshan he wants to open accordion on desktop view. So your answer is wrong. Please check again.

Comment: @saravana check my pen again. I did some modifications

Comment: @Gulshan Perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems proper. You just need to remove first `$(document).ready` function from the top as you already have called to the bottom. Also, I have updated code for `$(window).resize`.

```js
function resize() {
    var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem');
     if ($(window).width() > 992) {
      if (collapseItem) {
        $(collapseItem).collapse('show');
      }
    } else {
      if (collapseItem) {
        $(collapseItem).collapse('hide');
        localStorage.clear();
      }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
  resize();
  $('.link').click(function () {
    //store the id of the collapsible element
    if(localStorage.getItem("collapseItem") !== null) {
        localStorage.clear();
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
    }
  });
});
$(window).resize(resize);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
      aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Link with href
    </a>
  </p>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim
      keffiyeh
      helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please try the code after removing browsers localStorage.

I hope this helps.

Comment: When I close collapse its still open after page reload. The action should work open/close method.

Comment: @Saravana I have updated code based on your requirement. Please let me know if this helps.